# Pass variables to all Jinja2 templates with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a table in the navigation system of my webapp that will be populated with up-to-date information each time a page is rendered. How could I avoid putting the following code in each `view`?

```
def myview():
    mydict = code_to_generate_dict() 
    return render_template('main_page.html',mydict=mydict)
```

`mydict` is used to populate the table. The table will show up on each page

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [Flask's Context Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#context-processors) to inject globals into your jinja templates

Here is an example:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_dict_for_all_templates():
    return dict(mydict=code_to_generate_dict())
```

> To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template,
>   context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the
>   template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into
>   the template context. A context processor is a function that returns a
>   dictionary. The keys and values of this dictionary are then merged
>   with the template context, for all templates in the app:

Comment: So it's not confusing for others, maybe mention that Flask is looking for a `dict` to be returned, whether my variable to be injected is a `string`, `list`, or any other datatype (including a `dict`)

Comment: Josh J, you are right, but i have problem with project with more views files. How can i implement context_processor in more files? Context_processor must be in all files or can i use more systematic solution? Thank you.

Comment: @lukassliacky `context_processor` is on the Flask application object so it works for any view processed by that application. If you have multiple applications, then you would need to repeat it.

Comment: @JoshJ thanks for prompt answer. I mean one project with more complex structure and more views files. E.g.: `app/customer/views_customer.py, app/results/views_results.py` Must i use separate `context_processor` for every views file?

Comment: One per Flask instance (`app = Flask(...)`). If those views are all serviced by the previous `app`, then they share context.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem for the _generic menu_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a decorator, you can pass a function where the necessary context processor will be

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.context_processor(templatetags)

def templatetags():
    def format_price(amount, currency="€"):
        return f"{amount:.2f}{currency}"

    return dict(
        format_price=format_price,
    )
```

'index.html'

```
{{ format_price(0.33) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own render method do keep yourself from repeating that code. Then call it whenever you need to render a template.

```
def render_with_dict(template):
    mydict = code_to_generate_dict() 
    return render_template(template, mydict=mydict)

def myview():
    return render_with_dict('main_page.html')
```

Comment: Josh's answer did not require that I modify all of my existing templates